# Counting times over a limit based on months in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

So I'm trying to count all the vehicles that have been in a yard over 2 hours and then get the % of what vehicles have stayed in the yard over 2 hours for a month. I've tried doing it with a pivot table but the way the raw data is I can't get it to work so I came up with the solution in the picture but the countifs formula just constantly gives 0s back even after I copy and paste the contents of C into E16. Does anyone have a formula that would work?

-Edit
I've found it's because C still has the time information in it as well is there any way to remove the time and keep it date only?

[image]

Comment: Post data to question body as text so that we can copy/paste. Also put your formula to post.

Comment: *remove the time and keep it date only?*  Excel stores these values as days and fractions of a day.  So `INT(date-time) => date`